# List of objects, inventory system, stacking issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a simple RPG 3D game in unity. I am pretty much beginner at coding.
I've created a ScriptableObject class called Item so that i can simply create a new item and pass them properties from Inspector. Then I've created List to store items in characters Inventory. I've managed to make a code that adds the object to the list once they are picked up. The next step was an inventory UI - I've created 60 buttons that resemble slots in inventory and a pop out menu that shows up after pressing on them. The menu contains two buttons - Use and Remove. I'm creating Listeners for Use and Remove buttons once the menu is opened and if any of these is pressed i call method Use or Remove. I am storing information about the chosen inventory slot in an object of Item class.

Now the problem is - whenever i click multiple times on different items in inventory, even though i'm constantly trying to reset chosen object to null, somehow information about chosen item stacks. Once i press Use or Remove - each item that I've clicked is going to be affected.

Unity console is showing me (via Debug.Log) that I've entered a method with one object set, but when the method goes further - it's being done multiple times for each item clicked before. I am confused.

**Code for ScriptableObject Item**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Item", menuName = "Inventory/Item")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{

new public string name = "New Item";
public Sprite icon = null;
public Image itemImage;
public bool isDefaultItem = false;
[TextArea(3, 10)]
public string ItemInfo;
public GameObject Prefab;
public Animator chestObtain;

public virtual void Use()
{
    // Use the item

    Debug.Log("Using " + name);
}


}
```

**Code for Inventory (items storing)**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{

public int space = 30;

#region Singleton

public delegate void OnItemChanged();
public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;

public static Inventory instance;

private void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("More than one instance of Inventory found!");
        instance = this;
    }
}

#endregion

public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

public bool Add (Item item)
{
    if (!item.isDefaultItem)
    {
        if (items.Count >= space)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not enough space");
            return false;
        }
        items.Add(item);
        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        {
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        }
    }

    return true;

}

public void Remove(Item item)
{
    Debug.Log("Removing " + item);
    items.Remove(item);
    if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
    {
        onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
    }
}

public void RemoveAt(int i)
{
    if (i <= items.Count)
    {
        Debug.Log("Removing " + items[i]);
        Debug.Log("List: " + items);
        //items.RemoveAt(i);
        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        {
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Code for Inventory methods**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class InventoryItemInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject ItemInfoTab;
public bool ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
public Button OpenTab;
public Text Title;
public Text UseButtonText;
public Text RemoveButtonText;
public Text ItemInfo;
public int SlotID;
public Image ItemImage;
public Item test;
public Button RemoveButton;
public Button UseButton;

Inventory inventory;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
    {
        ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
    }
}

public void OpenTabPressed()
{
    Debug.Log("test object after opening a tab: " + test);
    test = null;
    Debug.Log("test object after opening a tab and reseting: " + test);
    UseButton.onClick.RemoveListener(OnUseButton);
    RemoveButton.onClick.RemoveListener(OnRemoveButton);

    if (ItemInfoTab.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
    }
    int itemsCount = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<Inventory>().items.Count;
    if (test == null)
    {
        if (itemsCount > SlotID)
        {

            if (ItemInfoTabIsOpen == false)
            {
                ItemInfoTab.SetActive(true);
                ItemInfoTabIsOpen = true;
            }
            test = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<Inventory>().items[SlotID];
            UseButton.onClick.AddListener(OnUseButton);
            RemoveButton.onClick.AddListener(OnRemoveButton);
            Debug.Log("SlotID: " + SlotID);
            Debug.Log("Clicked item: " + test);
            Title.text = test.name;
            ItemInfo.text = test.ItemInfo;
            ItemImage.sprite = test.icon;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Emtpy inventory slot");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        test = null;
        Debug.Log("Test object set to null");
    }
}

public void OnUseButton()
{
    Debug.Log("test object to use: " + test);
        test.Use();
        test = null;
    Debug.Log("test object after using: " + test);
}

public void OnRemoveButton()
{
    ItemInfoTab.SetActive(false);
    ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
    Debug.Log("test object to remove: " + test);
    FindObjectOfType<Inventory>().Remove(test);
    test = null;
}
}
```

Last note - I've put all of these *"test = null";* to try to overcome the issue but it didn't work.

---

### **Edit**

I've just noticed in inspector that once i click on item and it's assigned to the slot in inventory - it's only getting empty after calling Use or Remove method - never in any other conditions (and it should after clicking onto other item).

Screenshot for empty slot https://prnt.sc/rezehc
Screenshot for occupied slot Screenshot2

Idea - does this mean i am only resetting a "object variable" in script and not on actual item slot? If yes - how to set it back to null?
I've got over 60 item slots that look like this -> [Hierarchy](https://prnt.sc/rezg3a)
Each action button contains the same script (look previous screenshots).

---

Comment: its not 100% clear to me, as its not clear what scripts are where, but if you are adding onclick listeners to the use button  when its no longer the current object you need to remove it, you maybe getting into a situation where you are repeatedly adding listeners, but never removing them, so will end up with it happening multiple times

Comment: I've added RemoveListener to a part of code that's being called whenever a new item is clicked in "Code for inventory methods" (OpenTabPressed). 

I had the same feeling.

Comment: Add some debug logs showing adding and removing listeners...

Answer (score 3):

When you call `RemoveListener`, you have to call with a reference to the method of the instance it was called with before. Basically, you'd have to get a reference to the previous `InventoryItemInfo` then call:

```
UseButton.onClick.RemoveListener(previousInventoryItemInfo.OnUseButton);
RemoveButton.onClick.RemoveListener(previousInventoryItemInfo.OnRemoveButton);
```

Well, you don't seem to have a reference to that easily available. I'd recommend simply using [`RemoveAllListeners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEventBase.RemoveAllListeners.html):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class InventoryItemInfo : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public GameObject ItemInfoTab;
    public bool ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
    public Button OpenTab;
    public Text Title;
    public Text UseButtonText;
    public Text RemoveButtonText;
    public Text ItemInfo;
    public int SlotID;
    public Image ItemImage;
    public Item test;
    public Button RemoveButton;
    public Button UseButton;

    Inventory inventory;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public void OpenTabPressed()
    {
        Debug.Log("test object after opening a tab: " + test);
        test = null;
        Debug.Log("test object after opening a tab and reseting: " + test);
        UseButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        RemoveButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();

        if (ItemInfoTab.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
        }
        int itemsCount = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<Inventory>().items.Count;
        if (test == null)
        {
            if (itemsCount > SlotID)
            {

                if (ItemInfoTabIsOpen == false)
                {
                    ItemInfoTab.SetActive(true);
                    ItemInfoTabIsOpen = true;
                }
                test = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<Inventory>().items[SlotID];
                UseButton.onClick.AddListener(OnUseButton);
                RemoveButton.onClick.AddListener(OnRemoveButton);
                Debug.Log("SlotID: " + SlotID);
                Debug.Log("Clicked item: " + test);
                Title.text = test.name;
                ItemInfo.text = test.ItemInfo;
                ItemImage.sprite = test.icon;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Emtpy inventory slot");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            test = null;
            Debug.Log("Test object set to null");
        }
    }

    public void OnUseButton()
    {
        Debug.Log("test object to use: " + test);
            test.Use();
            test = null;
        Debug.Log("test object after using: " + test);
    }

    public void OnRemoveButton()
    {
        ItemInfoTab.SetActive(false);
        ItemInfoTabIsOpen = false;
        Debug.Log("test object to remove: " + test);
        FindObjectOfType<Inventory>().Remove(test);
        test = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it works! Now I have few new bugs to cover but my biggest concern 
has been dispelled.

Thank you kindly!